# How to add dropdown-menu based on other dropdown-menu using Ajax call in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm having two dropdown fields which is based on one another Class & Section.
I want

```
Select * from sections where class_id=selected Class Id.
```

I used **java script** to manage that but it is not working for me.

My **dropdown fields**

```
     <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" name = "class">
                    <option value="0">Please Select Category</option>
                    @foreach($classses as $classs)
                        <option value="{{$classs->id}}">{{$classs->title}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Products</label>
                <select class="form-control" name = "section">
                    <option value="0">Please Select Product</option>
                    @foreach($sections as $section)
                        <option value="{{$section->id}}">{{$section->title}}</option>
                    @endforeach

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('select[name=classs]').on('change', function () {
        var selected = $(this).find(":selected").attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + '/classs/'+selected+'/sections/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',

        }).done(function (data) {

            var select = $('select[name=section]');
            select.empty();
            select.append('<option value="0" >Please Select Product</option>');
            $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                select.append('<option value=' + key.id + '>' + value.title + '</option>');
            });
            console.log("success");
        })
    });
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/dropdown','DropDownController@index'); 
Route::get('classs/{id}/sections', 'DropDownController@getSection');
```

**Dropdown Controller**

```
 public function index(){

    $classses = Classs::all();
    $sections =Section::all();

    return view('classs.a', compact('classses','sections'));
}



   public function getSection($id){
    if($id!=0){

        $sections = Classs::find($id)->sections()->select('id', 'title')->get()->toArray();
    }else{
        $sections = Section::all()->toArray();
    }
    return response()->json($sections);
}
}
```

**Classs Modal**

```
  class Classs extends Model
{
//
    protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'title',

];

public function section()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Section');

}

  }
```

**Section Modal**

```
          class Section extends Model
{
//
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'title',
    'class_id',  //foreign key of Classs
    'user_id',

];

public function classs()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Classs');
}
```

But in actual when I get result, it gets all the classes & all the sections.
It maybe some error in syntax. I m so stuck. Please help me in this case.

Comment: Your input is called `class` but in JS you are looking for `name=classs`.

Comment: Are you talking about   <select class="form-control" name = "class">
 in dopdown field ?

Comment: Exactly. You can add a `console.log` inside the `change` listener to see if it gets called.

Comment: I changed it but it didn't work for me ..

Comment: Can you please elaborate more where can I add console.log

Comment: Is the function being called correctly? Does it actually perform the ajax request? Add the log just above `var selected = ...`

Comment: nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make sure if your JS is getting called directly.

Add a couple of `console.log` calls to the script:

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log('listening for change event', $('select[name=classs]')[0]);

    $('select[name=classs]').on('change', function () {
        var selected = $(this).find(":selected").attr('value');
        console.log('change event fired. selected value:', selected);
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + '/classs/'+selected+'/sections/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',

        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log('ajax response', data);

            var select = $('select[name=section]');
            select.empty();
            select.append('<option value="0" >Please Select Product</option>');
            $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                select.append('<option value=' + key.id + '>' + value.title + '</option>');
            });
            console.log("success");
        })
    });
});
```

Now check:

1. Is `listening for change event` logged on page load, with the correct element as a parameter?
2. Is `change event fired` logged on select value change, with the correct value?
3. Is `ajax response` logged with the correct data (id, title)?

Comment: only white page displayed when called.

Comment: i was missing </script> now page loads but no console message shows.

Comment: That's weird. Is anything else getting logged? Try adding `console.log(jQuery);` before `jQuery(document)` to see if jQuery is actually loaded.